# What's my initiator level for maneuvers from Martial Study?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat-maneuver, tome-of-battle

I'm building a Warblade/Master of Nine using the rules in Tome of Battle: Book of Nine Swords. To qualify for MoN, I'm using the Martial Study feat to take maneuvers from disciplines that a Warblade normally doesn't have access to.

When I take a maneuver outside my normal disciplines, am I treated as an initiator (using my Warblade level) or as a character with no initiator levels (using 1/2 my character level)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You use your warblade initiator level.**

From Tome of Battle, p31-32, Martial Study:

> ... If you have martial adept levels, this maneuver becomes one of your maneuvers known. If you do not have martial adept levels, you can use this maneuver once per encounter as a martial adept with an initiator level equal to 1/2 your character level.

If you have any levels in any martial adept class (crusader, swordsage, warblade) when you take the feat, then the maneuver you gain from Martial Study is just like any other maneuver you know from those classes: it uses the same recharge mechanic and the same initiator level.