# Tome of battle initiator levels manuvers

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

When using feats like Martial Stance and Martial study, Can you take a stance that requires swordsage levels over 1? 
To re-ask: Does initiator level = levels in swordsage needed for manuvers and stances (for example assasins stance wich has the prerequisite (Level: Swordsage 3). ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What's my initiator level for maneuvers from Martial Study?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15705/whats-my-initiator-level-for-maneuvers-from-martial-study?rq=1), although the body of that question is actually more specific than the title.

Answer (score 6):

Martial Study allows you to learn maneuvers independently of any martial adept classes you might have, though it can benefit from the recovery method and initiator level of those classes if you have them.

If you have no levels in any martial adept class, your initiator level is equal to half your level.

- A 6th-level fighter has an Initiator Level of 3, and can take 2nd-level maneuvers with Martial Study.
- A 10th-level fighter has an Initiator Level of 5, and can take a 3rd-level stance with Martial Stance.

If you have levels in a single martial adept class, your initiator level is equal to your levels in that class, plus half your levels in any other classes.

- A 4th-level warblade/2nd-level fighter has an initiator level of 5, and thus can take 3rd-level maneuvers with Martial Study and 3rd-level stances with Martial Stance. These are added as warblade maneuvers (even if they are not normally available to warblades), and thus use the warblade recovery method and must be readied using the warblade maneuvers readied.

If you have levels in multiple martial adept classes, you have *separate initiator levels in each* equal to your levels in that class, plus half your levels in any other classes, *including the other initiating classes.*

- A 4th-level warblade/2nd-level swordsage has a warblade initiator level of 5, and thus can use Martial Study and Martial Stance to add 3rd-level maneuvers and stances as warblade maneuvers and stances, and also has a swordsage initiator level of 4, and could add 2nd-level maneuvers (and stances, if there were any) as swordsage manevers (there is no reason to do this, but one could).

When you use Martial Study or Martial Stance, it doesn’t matter what class a maneuver is usually associated with; these feats explicitly allow you to get maneuvers you usually couldn’t. All that matters is that you meet the prerequisites for the maneuver, including the minimum initiator level. If you are an initiator already, the maneuver is added as a maneuver known for that class. If not, you just get the maneuver once per encounter, with no method of recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Martial Study allows you to learn maneuvers independently of any initiating classes you might have, though it can benefit from the recovery method and initiator level of those classes if you have them.

If you have no levels in any initiating class, your initiator level is equal to half your level plus one.

A 6th-level fighter has an Initiator Level of 3, and can take 2nd-level maneuvers with Martial Study.
A 10th-level fighter has an Initiator Level of 5, and can take a 3rd-level stance with Martial Stance.

Comment: What is your basis for saying “plus one” here? My copy of *Tome of Battle* says “If you do not have martial adept levels, you can use this maneuver once per encounter as a martial adept with an initiator level equal to 1/2 your character level,” no mention of adding one. At *best*, I have heard suggestion of having a *minimum* of initiator level 1st for these purposes (elsewise you qualify for Martial Study but cannot actually learn any maneuvers if you take it, which is pretty nonsensical), though I’m pretty sure the book neglects to spell even that out.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. I urge putting this answer into your own words instead of copying another answer and making changes to it (no matter how good that other answer may be)—it's not only polite but makes it obvious that nothing untoward is going on. I also recommend citing—using quotations from the text and page numbers—rules information, especially information that has a dramatic impact on the answer. Rules discussions are much easier to have when we're all on the same page. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: By your calculation, a second level non-initiator has the same level as a single classed initiator.